# List with ajax-loading details in AngularJS

Tags: ajax, angularjs

For a list of items I want to show details after item click. Details will be loaded with ajax request.
I have something similar to this: http://jsfiddle.net/asmKj/
How to modify this to work with details loaded dynamically?

For sure I have to prepare function in my controller like this:

```
$scope.getDetails = function (name) {
    return $scope.details = myService.getDetails(name).then(function (details) {
        return $scope.details = details;
    });
}
```

But how to bind this data to details div?

Comment: would be nice if you show us how `details` and `showDetails` are actually structured? and if it is possible to reorganize this structure... (if needed of course)

Comment: go through tutorial on docs site. It is perfect example of what you want

Answer (score 2):

I would rather change with something like this:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="procedures" ng-app ng-controller="sample">
    <li ng-repeat="procedure in procedures">
        <h4><a href="#" ng-click="getDetails($index)">{{procedure.definition}}</a></h4>
         <div class="procedure-details" ng-show="procedures.isVisible">
            <p>Number of patient discharges: {{procedure.discharged}}</p>
         </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.procedures = [
    {
        definition: 'Procedure 1',
        discharged: 23
    },
    {
        definition: 'Procedure 2',
        discharged: 2
    },
    {
        definition: 'Procedure 3',
        discharged: 356
    }
];

$scope.getDetails = function ($index) {
    $http.get('your-url').success(
       // use the data retrieved
       procedures[$index].isVisible = !procedures[$index].isVisible;
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two options.

1. Put everything in your `procedure` objects as separate properties (when the details are loaded) -- then you can just use `procedure.showDetails` in `ng-repeat`.
2. Use `$index` to get index from your `procedures` -- then you can use it to access any arbitrary collection from your scope in `ng-repeat`.

(may update my answer, when you provide more info about structure of your data; and if still needed)